# What is this Class comparison doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('body').find('.grid-container > .parsys .parsys')
```

I found this in a bit of code and I'm not exactly sure what it is comparing and why there are two Classes following the greater than symbol. Is it trying to find a specific hierarchy? and if that's the case then why the second Class?

Comment: Did you try google? Did you try jQuery documentation?

Comment: There are in fact no IDs in that selector. If you were to read the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) you'd easily be able to determine what this selector does.

Comment: @zzzBov  i meant class not ID (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't IDs.
the code inside find('...') and $('...') are selectors.

Selector allow you to manipulate HTML elements.
The code will search in body a element with the class "parsys" inside a element with the class "parsys" where the parent is a element with the class "grid-container".

```
...
<body>
<div class="grid-container>
  <div class="parsys">
    <div class="otherElementOrNot">
       <div  class="parsys">
           this div is the target.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

In a jQuery ( or css) selector the greater than sign `>` is not used for comparison. It means an immediate child of the element.

Also note that the leading dot means it is a class selector not an id. For ids we use the `#` symbol.

```
.class .selector {}
#id .selector {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no `id` selectors (starting with `#`), but there are class selectors (starting with `.`).

There is no comparison, CSS selector `>` specifies rules for direct children of the parent element (`.grid-container`).

The code above searches for elements with class `.parsys` that are descendants of elements with class `.parsys` that are direct children (`>` selector) of elements with class `.grid-container` within `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

the first id represents the element that should be present under grid-container as a direct child. 
Second id represents any element at any level under .parsys

Answer (score 0):

This will find all elements that have this basic nested structure. Only the inner-most div in this example would be matched.

```
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="parsys">
            <div class="parsys">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this finding elements with class .parsys within an element with class .parsys directly below the element with class .grid-container?

```
<div class=".grid-container">
  <div class=".parsys">
    <div class=".parsys" [matched]>
    </div>
    <div class=".parsys" [matched]>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```